# goapp build clang: warning: argument unused during compilation

Tags: google-app-engine, go

After upgraded to `go_appengine` 1.9.54, I always get following warnings
during

`$ goapp build`

clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread'
...

Note: `$ go build` works fine. I'm running on `macOS (Sierra)`

Is the `-pthread` flag mandatory for building an golang app via `goapp`? Or should I ignore these warnings?